# Signal Dimensions in Simulink

Tags: signal, dsp, fourier, simulink, spectrum-analyzer

I'm using R2022a, in Simulink I can not find the Display tab to access Signals & Ports>Signal Dimensions. Could someone point me in the right direction please?. Also, in the figure below the dimensions are 5x1. The signals are () = 5 sin(210), how was the 5x1 dimension determined by the program? What are the parameters that affect the signal dimension? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The signals are () = 5 sin(210), how was the 5x1 dimension determined by the program?

In MATLAB everything is a vector. If you try to write the following code

```
x = cos(2*pi*t);
```

MATLAB will complain, because it doesn't know what `t` is. You need to first define `t` as a vector (or a number) if you want to use it.

```
fs = 20;             %Define sampling frequency
t = 0:1/fs:2-1/fs;   %Create time vector with 1/fs increment
x = cos(2*pi*t);     %Create function vector from t
plot(t,x)
```

`x` and `t` have the same dimensions. You can find the dimensions of a vector using the `size` command. In my case, I get

```
>> size(t)

ans =

    1     40
```

because my `t` vector has 1 row and 40 columns. This is what a signal dimension in MATLAB is.

> I can not find the Display tab to access Signals & Ports>Signal Dimensions. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

[image]